# Custom Payload with dialogflow on google plateform

Tags: dialogflow-es, chatbot, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I am trying to sent custom payload in an dialogflot intent. When i am selecting the custom payload option available under google assistant it gives the following predefined json format : -

```
{
  "google": {

   }
}
```

now i am not aware about what i need to put in there in order to get a response from here. Any guide will be helpful

Comment: You say you want to use the custom payload, but you're not clear about what you want to include there that is different from the defined payload types that you can do through Dialogflow directly. Can you update your question with what, exactly, you're trying to accomplish? If you have already tried putting things in the payload, can you show what you've done but didn't work?

Answer (score 1):

There are some compulsory Keys to be added in Rich Response JSON.
You must have Suggestion Chips and a Simple Response to maintain the follow-up of your Action. AoG rejects any action with missing Suggestion Chips or Follow-Up Response.

Refer to this JSON for Basic Card Response:

```
{
  "payload": {
    "google": {
      "expectUserResponse": true,
      "richResponse": {
        "items": [
          {
            "simpleResponse": {
              "textToSpeech": "Here's an example of a basic card."
            }
          },
          {
            "basicCard": {
              "title": "Title: this is a title",
              "subtitle": "This is a subtitle",
              "formattedText": "This is a basic card.  Text in a basic card can include \"quotes\" and\n    most other unicode characters including emojis.  Basic cards also support\n    some markdown formatting like *emphasis* or _italics_, **strong** or\n    __bold__, and ***bold itallic*** or ___strong emphasis___ as well as other\n    things like line  \nbreaks",
              "image": {
                "url": "https://storage.googleapis.com/actionsresources/logo_assistant_2x_64dp.png",
                "accessibilityText": "Image alternate text"
              },
              "buttons": [
                {
                  "title": "This is a button",
                  "openUrlAction": {
                    "url": "https://assistant.google.com/"
                  }
                }
              ],
              "imageDisplayOptions": "CROPPED"
            }
          },
          {
            "simpleResponse": {
              "textToSpeech": "Which response would you like to see next?"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You can refer to the specific Rich Response JSON for your Action in the following Documentation:
https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/rich-responses#df-json-basic-card